# Excel Sum Product

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula, excel-2010

Currently in my excel spreadsheet i have this formula in one of my cell

```
=SUMPRODUCT(('CDT DWGS-2014'!G:G=2014)*
            ('CDT DWGS-2014'!S:S<>"")*
            ('CDT DWGS-2014'!Q:Q>='CDT DWGS-2014'!S:S)*
            ('CDT DWGS-2014'!S:S>=DATEVALUE("01-Jan-2014"))*
            ('CDT DWGS-2014'!S:S<DATEVALUE("01-Feb-2014"))
  )
```

i want to add this next line of code into the previous code but it keeps giving me a #value error.

```
*('CDT DWGS-2014'!T:T>1)*
```

is it because in the column T, i have both numbers and text in there? How would i go about getting the sum product value without changing the column T? I need both number and text in the column. In each cell in column T, it's either "Jon Not Finished" or negative or positive numbers

Thank you

Comment: check whether your column `T` has any errors, e.g. using this formula: `=SUMPRODUCT(1*(ISERROR('CDT DWGS-2014'!T:T)))`? what it returns?

Comment: your column contains error - most likely `#VALUE` - and this is the reason of error of your formula

Comment: Can you share your workbook (e.g. using https://www.dropbox.com)? Without seeing your workbook it's difficult to find right solution

Comment: It's ok Simoco, i found the problem. I was just an idiot. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the values in column **T** contain positive values or negative values or a text string, but not zero then replace the text values with the value zero and format these zero cells as Custom

**;;"Jon Not Finished";**

These cells will show the text, but behave like zero!